# Formik: Need to render forms differently based on values in sibling forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

```
<ParentComponent>
...
  <Formik
    initialValues={getInitialValues(data)}
    enableReinitialize={true}
    validationSchema={schema}
    isInitialValid={!isNew}
    onSubmit={() => {}}
    render={formikProps => (
      <SimulatorForm>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${match.url}/:id/form1`}>
            <FormOne {...formikProps} setTab={setTab} />
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${match.url}/:id/form2`}>
            <Form2 {...formikProps} setTab={setTab} />
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${match.url}/:id/form3`}>
            <FormThree {...formikProps} setTab={setTab} />
          </Route>
          {simulatorDebug && (
            <Route path={`${match.url}/:id/form4`}>
              <FormFour {...formikProps} setTab={setTab} />
            </Route>
          )}
          <Redirect to={`${match.url}/${cloneId}/customer`} />
...
</ParentComponent>
```

Essentially, my issue is that I need to render FormThree differently based on what values are selected in FormTwo.
FormTwo has a select dropdown box:

```
        <FormGroup
          name={"value_options"}
          label={"Value Options"}
          required
          render={() => (
            <SelectDropDown
              options={valueOptions}
              value={valueOptions.find(
                opt => opt.value === values.valueOptions
              )}
              onChange={opt => {
                setFieldValue("value_options", opt.value);
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
```

And based on the "value option" selected in this dropdown, I will render FormThree differently. I feel like there is a way I need to keep track of the state of that selected option, but I'm not sure how I would pass it from component to component.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: Props

Each of your number form page components is already being called with props `{...formikProps} setTab={setTab}`  The `formikProps` object has type `FormikProps<Values>` where the `Values` generic describes the values of your form.  `formikProps.values` will be an object with all of the current values of the form.  So any of your components can access all of the form values, no matter where they are controlled.

```
// the state type for your form
interface MyFormState {
  value_options: string;
  // add other properties
}

// props for `FormOne`, `FormTwo`, etc.
type FormPageProps = FormikProps<MyFormState> & {
  setTab: (tab: string /* or whatever it is really */) => void;
}

const FormThree: React.FC<FormPageProps> = (props) => {

  // can access `value_options` from props
  const {value_options} = props.values

  // change behavior based on value_options
  ...
}
```

---

#### Solution 2: Context

The `Formik` component serves as a React Context provider.  You can use the hook [`useFormikContext`](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext) to access the form state in any descendant of the `Formik` component.  You will need to set the `<Values>` generic on this hook in order for Typescript to know the type of your form's `values` object.

```
// no longer need the form props
const FormThree: React.FC = () => {

  // can access `value_options` from context
  const { values } = useFormikContext<MyFormState>();
  const {value_options} = values

  // change behavior based on value_options
  ...
}
```

---

I recommend Solution #1 in this case since you are already passing down the required props.  You just need to make sure that your components have the right Typescript types so that they are able to access the values from those props.